# Asserting all checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine

I have 5 checkboxes with the same name property `relative-view`.

I want to assert that all of them are checked.  I can do this to check the first and last one

```
expect(element.find('input[name="relative-view"]').first().prop("checked")).toBe(true);
expect(element.find('input[name="relative-view"]').last().prop("checked")).toBe(true);
```

But I don't know how to check them all.  I have tried the following but I get an error saying undefined is not a function

```
expect(element.find('input[name="relative-view"]')[0].prop("checked")).toBe(true);
expect(element.find('input[name="relative-view"]')[1].prop("checked")).toBe(true);
expect(element.find('input[name="relative-view"]')[2].prop("checked")).toBe(true);
expect(element.find('input[name="relative-view"]')[3].prop("checked")).toBe(true);
expect(element.find('input[name="relative-view"]')[4].prop("checked")).toBe(true);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[n]` notation returns DOM elements which don't have `.prop()` - that's jQuery API. Use `.eq()`:

```
var boxes = element.find('input[name="relative-view"]');

expect(boxes.eq(0).prop("checked")).toBe(true);
expect(boxes.eq(1).prop("checked")).toBe(true);
expect(boxes.eq(2).prop("checked")).toBe(true);
expect(boxes.eq(3).prop("checked")).toBe(true);
expect(boxes.eq(4).prop("checked")).toBe(true);
```

An alternative approach would be to use the standard `.checked` property:

```
var boxes = element.find('input[name="relative-view"]').get();

expect(boxes[0].checked).toBe(true);
expect(boxes[1].checked).toBe(true);
expect(boxes[2].checked).toBe(true);
expect(boxes[3].checked).toBe(true);
expect(boxes[4].checked).toBe(true);
```

Also, try just iterating over the jQuery collection:

```
$('input[name="relative-view"]', element).each(function () {
    expect(this.checked).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Or `collection === collection.filter(':checked').length`.

Comment: Correction: it was supposed to be `collection.length === collection.filter(':checked').length`, I missed the `length` in my last edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function which will go through all checkboxes and return `false` if any of them is not checked. Use:

```
function CheckAllCheckboxes(){
    var _RetValue = true;
    $('input[name="relative-view"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") != true)
            _RetValue = false;
            return false; // quit from each()
    }
    return _RetValue;
}
```

Then you can use

```
expect(CheckAllCheckboxes()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Probably because each function has it's own returned value?

Comment: In other words, your `CheckAllCheckboxes` function will always return `true`. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEx4gjC2MObh30cPddXD?p=preview) is one way you could modify it to make it work as you intended.